# Can you detect a ctrl-click (context menu) request in the mouseDown event?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

In my cross-platform architecture, I would like to act on a context menu click (right button click) during a mouse click event.  In Cocoa, can you detect that the user either Ctrl-Clicked or double-tapped on touchpad (right-click equivalent) DURING the mouseDown event?  I am aware of NSView's menuForEvent but do not wish to handle it here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using AppKit, and you want to detect a right-click in your view, you should override `-[NSResponder rightMouseDown:]`.

Comment: Duh.  I don't know how I missed that event. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

In general, -rightMouseDown: should get called automatically, but I've seen situations where it isn't -- these may be patched in Leopard.

But right now, in -mouseDown: I check whether the control key is down, using this code:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event;
{
    if (event.modifierFlags & NSControlKeyMask)
        return [self rightMouseDown:event];

...
}
```

-Wil

Answer (score 1):

Swift version:

```
override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    if theEvent.modifierFlags.contains(.ControlKeyMask) {
        return rightMouseDown(theEvent)
    }

    super.mouseDown(theEvent)
}
```